# Android AsyncLoader.onPostExecute not execute

Tags: java, android

I made a simple android sample, used `AsyncLoader` to read the html and put the page value on the `Textfield`.

Previously, it worked perfectly. Now I added a service to it, and I found AsyncLoader failed. `AsyncLoader.onPostExecute` would never be executed...

Here is the code...

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    AirCondition = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.air);
    AsyncLoader load = new AsyncLoader();
    load.execute();
    StartService();
}
public class AsyncLoader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            air = CommonMethod.GetAirCondition();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
    protected void onPreExecute() {}
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        if (result) {
            AirCondition.setText(air);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the service onStartCommand I declared...

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
    try{
        while(true)
        {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            new Thread(){
                public void run()
                {
                    String result = CommonMethod.GetAirCondition();
                    if(Integer.parseInt(result.trim()) > 10)
                    {
                        Log.i("Allen","fuck");
                    }
                }
            }.start();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `@Override`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `onPostExecute()` and `doInBackground()` should be annotated with `@override`:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    ...
```

Your `onPreExecute()` can be removed as default implementation does nothing.